# Upload file and display content in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new at RStudio's Shiny. I would like to upload a file and display it's content. So far I have the code provided here http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload-widget.html 
How do I save the uploaded file's content into a variable and then display it?

Comment: There are lots of resources provided by RStudio, check them out for tips: [file upload](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) and [display](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html).

Comment: I'm aware of those. I meant i would like to upload for instance somerandomfile.txt and then display all it's content on the page. Let's say somerandomfile.txt has the content: Hello world. When i upload this .txt i want Hello world to show up under it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would get you started. It's obviously very rough code (it doesn't even sanitize the input, and it has an error shown to the user until a file is selected), but it'll give you an idea of how to upload, read, and show a file.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Select a file"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    filePath <- input$file$datapath
    fileText <- paste(readLines(filePath), collapse = "\n")
    fileText
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```